# show content of each page when link us clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is example which shows content of different div on when button is clicked.

Fidddle: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/NHtvM/15/

Rather then div, I want to display the content of different page when link is clicked. 
There must not appear scroll bar.

Header and footer should remain fixed. how to do this?

JS:

```
$(function () {
    // Scroll to function
    function scrollTo(ele) {
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $(ele).offset().top - $("header").outerHeight()
        });
    }

    // Detect location hash
    if (window.location.hash) {
        scrollTo(window.location.hash);
    }

    // Detect click event
    $("header a[href^='#']").click(function (e) {
        var target = $(this).attr("href");
        scrollTo(target);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: You can simply show/hide divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If content is loaded you can hide-show what you need. If by page you mean a external page you can call the resource with a ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/user/login/",
        context: document.body
    }).done(function(data) {
        target.html(data);
        scrollTo(target);
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2LCM4/

Comment: thanks, but I dont want to show scroll bar on the page. and also at a time content of only one page should appear. Each of them should appear independant and isolated